# "Missing Keyword" When creating a table in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

I keep getting

> "SQL Error: ORA - 00905: missing keyword" in the "CREATE TABLE"

portions of my code shown below:

```
    CREATE TABLE Orders (
    Received CHAR(9),
    Shipped CHAR(9),
    FOREIGN KEY (Ono), REFERENCES Odetails (Ono),
    FOREIGN KEY (Cno), REFERENCES customers (Cno),
    FOREIGN KEY (Eno), REFERENCES employee (Eno), 
    PRIMARY KEY (Ono, Cno, Eno)
    );

    CREATE TABLE ZIPCODES (
    ZIP CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    City CHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (ZIP), REFERENCES customers (ZIP),
    PRIMARY KEY (ZIP) 
    );
```

However, I wrote this code in the same worksheet and did not get any errors what so ever:

```
    CREATE TABLE Odetails (
    Ono CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    Pno CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Qty CHAR(1),
    FOREIGN KEY (Pno), REFERENCES parts (Pno),
    PRIMARY KEY (Ono) 
    );
```

Can anyone help me identify what is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Do not use comma

2) Define columns

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    Received CHAR(9),
    Shipped CHAR(9),
    Ono INT NOT NULL ,   -- your missing columns (add datatype you need)
    Cno INT NOT NULL,
    Eno INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Ono) REFERENCES Odetails (Ono),  -- here no comma inside
    FOREIGN KEY (Cno) REFERENCES customers (Cno),
    FOREIGN KEY (Eno) REFERENCES employee (Eno), 
    PRIMARY KEY (Ono, Cno, Eno)
    );

CREATE TABLE ZIPCODES (
    ZIP CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    City CHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (ZIP) REFERENCES customers (ZIP),
    PRIMARY KEY (ZIP) 
    );
```

Consider using `VARCHAR2` datatype instead of `CHAR`.

You could also use inline syntax like:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  ...
   Ono INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Odetails (Ono)
  ...
);
```

or add explicit constraint name:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
      ...
       Ono INT NOT NULL,
      ...
      CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Odetails_Ono  FOREIGN KEY (Ono) REFERENCES Odetails (Ono),
      ...
);
```

Comment: Also better use `VARCHAR2` instead of `CHAR` which is right-padded with blank space up to the size defined and is a wastage of storage.

Comment: The FK _can_ be defined inline: `Ono INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Odetails (Ono)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, this is one possibility. I've updated my answer + added version with explicit constraint name

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [comma](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) after foreign key so it should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
Received CHAR(9),
Shipped CHAR(9),
FOREIGN KEY (Ono) REFERENCES Odetails (Ono),--are you defining this Ono?
FOREIGN KEY (Cno) REFERENCES customers (Cno),
FOREIGN KEY (Eno) REFERENCES employee (Eno), 
PRIMARY KEY (Ono, Cno, Eno)
);
```